# How to set image placeholder like Instagram

Tags: java, android, image-processing, instagram, picasso

I heard Instagram uses the Picasso library for loading images, I was wondering if anyone can point how i can implement the image loading placeholder like Instagram, where a progress bar loads, in my app as i also use the Picasso library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Glide? It's very easy.

```
Glide.with(this).load("url")
                     .placeholder(R.drawable.xxx)
                     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Yes i know about glide, they are almost the same. What i want is the progress loading placeholder like in Instagram